# How to read firebase push notification content and fire a method in ionic2?

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, ionic2, ionic3

Is it possible to access `push notification` content in ionic 2 and execute bunch of code when notification arrive or `event fire`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd recommend using the [cordova-plugin-firebase](https://github.com/arnesson/cordova-plugin-firebase) instead. You can take a look at [this repo](https://github.com/sebaferreras/Ionic2-FirebaseDemo) to see how to use that plugin.

Please notice that you'd need first to configure the firebase console, and donwload the .json / .plist files and add them to the root folder of your Ionic app. Then you can start using the plugin.

In the demo everything is done in the `app.component.ts` file, but I recommend creating a `PushNotificationService` to keep everything organised.

Please also notice that the demo uses *topics* features, so devices can subscribe to specific topics, and then we can use these topics to send notifications to some group of users (only android or ios, only a specific user, all users from the app...):

```
this.firebase.subscribe('firebase-app'),    // Subscribe to the entire app
this.firebase.subscribe('android'),         // Subscribe to android users topic
this.firebase.subscribe('userid-1')         // Subscribe using the user id (hardcoded in this example)
```

This is all the related code:

```
// Angular
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

// Ionic
import { Platform, AlertController } from 'ionic-angular';

// Ionic Native
import { Firebase } from '@ionic-native/firebase';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';

// Pages
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';

export class NotificationModel {
    public body: string;
    public title: string;
    public tap: boolean
}

@Component({
    templateUrl: 'app.html'
})
export class MyApp {
    rootPage: any = HomePage;

    constructor(private platform: Platform,
        private alertCtrl: AlertController,
        private firebase: Firebase,
        private statusBar: StatusBar,
        private splashScreen: SplashScreen) {

        this.platform.ready().then(() => {
            this.statusBar.styleDefault();
            this.splashScreen.hide();

            if (this.platform.is('cordova')) {
                // Initialize push notification feature
                this.platform.is('android') ? this.initializeFireBaseAndroid() : this.initializeFireBaseIos();
            } else {
                console.log('Push notifications are not enabled since this is not a real device');
            }
        });
    }

    private initializeFireBaseAndroid(): Promise<any> {
        return this.firebase.getToken()
            .catch(error => console.error('Error getting token', error))
            .then(token => {

                console.log(`The token is ${token}`);

                Promise.all([
                    this.firebase.subscribe('firebase-app'),    // Subscribe to the entire app
                    this.firebase.subscribe('android'),         // Subscribe to android users topic
                    this.firebase.subscribe('userid-1')         // Subscribe using the user id (hardcoded in this example)
                ]).then((result) => {
                    if (result[0]) console.log(`Subscribed to FirebaseDemo`);
                    if (result[1]) console.log(`Subscribed to Android`);
                    if (result[2]) console.log(`Subscribed as User`);

                    this.subscribeToPushNotificationEvents();
                });
            });
    }

    private initializeFireBaseIos(): Promise<any> {
        return this.firebase.grantPermission()
            .catch(error => console.error('Error getting permission', error))
            .then(() => {
                this.firebase.getToken()
                    .catch(error => console.error('Error getting token', error))
                    .then(token => {

                        console.log(`The token is ${token}`);

                        Promise.all([
                            this.firebase.subscribe('firebase-app'),
                            this.firebase.subscribe('ios'),
                            this.firebase.subscribe('userid-2')
                        ]).then((result) => {

                            if (result[0]) console.log(`Subscribed to FirebaseDemo`);
                            if (result[1]) console.log(`Subscribed to iOS`);
                            if (result[2]) console.log(`Subscribed as User`);

                            this.subscribeToPushNotificationEvents();
                        });
                    });
            })

    }

    private saveToken(token: any): Promise<any> {
        // Send the token to the server
        console.log('Sending token to the server...');
        return Promise.resolve(true);
    }

    private subscribeToPushNotificationEvents(): void {

        // Handle token refresh
        this.firebase.onTokenRefresh().subscribe(
            token => {
                console.log(`The new token is ${token}`);
                this.saveToken(token);
            },
            error => {
                console.error('Error refreshing token', error);
            });

        // Handle incoming notifications
        this.firebase.onNotificationOpen().subscribe(
            (notification: NotificationModel) => {

                !notification.tap
                    ? console.log('The user was using the app when the notification arrived...')
                    : console.log('The app was closed when the notification arrived...');

                let notificationAlert = this.alertCtrl.create({
                    title: notification.title,
                    message: notification.body,
                    buttons: ['Ok']
                });
                notificationAlert.present();
            },
            error => {
                console.error('Error getting the notification', error);
            });
    }
}
```

---

Also please notice, that the content of the notification sent will not be the same if the app is running in the foreground or if the app is closed when the notification arrives. In order to handle that, when sending a notification, add the `title` and the `body` in the *Advanced options* section

[image: Example]

Comment: Hi @sebaferreras in fact tried to using  cordova-plugin-firebase, when app is in foreground and notification arrive app crashing (both Single Device and Segmented User) but when app is in back ground receiving without error. i have full description of the problem process in : https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/when-app-receive-push-notification-by-token-the-app-crashing/89893

Comment: Ok, I'll take a look at that post, because I'm using it exactly like in the answer and works as expected, there must be something wrong when handling the notification. Btw, did you notice that  when the app is closed, the `title` and `body` properties are not being send by firebase/the plugin? That's why I send the information in the custom data

Comment: when I use this code application Is not crashing but if this code is disabled app crash in both public and single device push notifications. Tnx

Comment: @sebaferreras I wish I had found your post 4 days ago, really neatly written and well presented, saved me many more hours of headache, if i could donate you a nice cold beer it would be on its way first class!

Comment: lol so glad to hear that it helped @C.KMunn. Thanks for your comment :)

Comment: its works in background only for android device, not work  for foreground mode

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is, you'll need a plugin to this, i use the [cordova-plugin-fcm](https://github.com/fechanique/cordova-plugin-fcm).

In your `app.ts` you can do the following

```
declare var FCMPlugin: any; //declare with the imports

FCMPlugin.onNotification(function(data){
  if(data.wasTapped){
    //Notification was received on device tray and tapped by the user.
    alert( JSON.stringify(data) );
  }else{
    //Notification was received in foreground. Maybe the user needs to be notified.
    alert( JSON.stringify(data) );
  }
});
```

Inside was tapper you'll do your code.

Hope this helps.

Comment: when I install FCM the fallowing error : Module '"E:/apps/myapp/node_modules/ionic-native/dist/es5/index"' has no exported member 'FCM'.