# Push notification is not working on Background

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, ionic-native

I'm using [**native firebase**](http://ionicframework.com/docs/native/firebase/) plugin's push notification feature.

**Current behavior:**

It is working fine with the foreground.But when the app is in the background and I try to tap the notification it shows `undefined`.Please see the video below.I have tested this on Anroid device.

**Expected behavior:**

When I tap the notification message it should open the app and show the message correctly.

**[Video](https://youtu.be/1lBzwf6grWs)**

**app.component.ts**

```
constructor(public platform: Platform)
{
    platform.ready().then(() => {
           this.onNotificationOpen();
      });
}

onNotificationOpen(): void {
        if (this.platform.is('cordova')) {
            this.firebase.onNotificationOpen()
                .subscribe(res => {
                    if (res.tap) {//background mode
                        console.log(res.body);
                        this.showAlert(res.body);
                    } else if (!res.tap) {//foreground mode
                        console.log(res.body);
                        this.showAlert(res.body);
                    }
                });
        }
    }

        showAlert(message: string): void {
        let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
            title: 'Push Notification',
            subTitle: message,
            buttons: ['OK']
        });
        alert.present();
    }
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "ionic-hello-world",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "4.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "4.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "4.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "4.1.0",
    "@angular/http": "4.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "4.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.1.0",
    "@ionic-native/core": "3.6.1",
    "@ionic-native/device": "3.6.1",
    "@ionic-native/facebook": "^3.10.0",
    "@ionic-native/firebase": "^3.10.3",
    "@ionic-native/keyboard": "^3.10.3",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "3.6.1",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "3.6.1",
    "@ionic/cli-plugin-cordova": "^1.2.0",
    "@ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular": "^1.2.0",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.0.1",
    "@ngrx/core": "^1.2.0",
    "@ngrx/store": "^2.2.1",
    "d3": "^4.7.4",
    "firebase": "^3.7.5",
    "ionic-angular": "3.2.1",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "moment": "^2.18.1",
    "pouchdb": "^6.1.2",
    "pouchdb-adapter-cordova-sqlite": "^2.0.2",
    "rxjs": "5.1.1",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.10"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "1.3.7",
    "@ionic/cli-plugin-cordova": "1.2.1",
    "@ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular": "1.2.0",
    "typescript": "~2.2.1"
  },
  "cordovaPlugins": [
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist",
    "cordova-plugin-console",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar",
    "cordova-plugin-device",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard"
  ],
  "cordovaPlatforms": [
    "ios",
    {
      "platform": "ios",
      "version": "",
      "locator": "ios"
    }
  ],
  "description": "helloWorld: An Ionic project"
}
```

Comment: Are you sending the push notification from the firebase console? I'm not using the same plugin, but please notice that AFAIK firebase doesn't send the same data in the notification when the app is running in the background (since the title and the body are shown in the notification itself). Please take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43928185/how-to-read-firebase-push-notification-content-and-fire-a-method-in-ionic2/43950976#43950976) (specially the last part of it)

Comment: Oh.... you're Great.Can you please put that last part here also with the Git repo link? Thanks @sebaferreras

Comment: Np! I've added those parts as requested :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend using the [cordova-plugin-firebase](https://github.com/arnesson/cordova-plugin-firebase) instead. You can take a look at [this repo](https://github.com/sebaferreras/Ionic2-FirebaseDemo) to see how to use that plugin.

Please notice that **the content of the notification sent will not be the same if the app is running in the foreground or if the app is closed when the notification arrives**. In order to handle that, when sending a notification, add the `title` and the `body` in the *Advanced options* section:

[image]

Comment: One question.Can you tell me what is the task of this method where you have used on Git repo `this.saveToken(token);`?

Comment: Is just used if you want to send the token of the user to your server

Comment: OK sure.Thanks :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46493420/ionic1-fcm-push-notification-custom-click/46501174#46501174 help @sebaferreras