# ionic1 fcm push notification custom click

Tags: cordova, firebase, ionic-framework

hi all i am using ionic1 push notification functionality with help of firebase 
here i mentioned used plugins

1.ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-inappbrowser

2.ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-fcm

3.ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-velda-devicefeedback

Once app open and in foreground then notify worked maybe i closed app and send notify it's not working help

Notification working fine i need when user click notify i am show alert box in my app and show the notify message in alert help

Answer (score 1):

When the application is in the background in order to get the click event you need to modify the data sending to the firebase api. Check this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/45325585/7140972 for the detailed answer.

Comment: In the server side you need to make this change. In order to initiate the notification we need to send data in the specified format to the firebase API created for your project.

Comment: in fcm plugin?pls explain little clear where i should format i am not add any code in my project just i add plugin mentioned below for push notifcation

Comment: There is nothing to change in the client side, this change should be made in the server side from which you initiate the notification. Are you using firebase console to trigger the notification? If so you can try sending the data as mentioned in the advanced option custom data part.

Comment: iam using firebase console but i am not initiate any notifcation in my code .help!

Comment: From firebase console you send the message with notification title and body, right? In the firebase console there is one advanced option where you can give the custom data as key value pairs. You can send the notification and data part as key value pair from there. Try adding "notification" as key and its value as the json object and do the same with data part also.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46602654/how-to-get-image-in-push-notfication-firebase-ionic