# how to get image in push notfication firebase ionic

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database, cordova-plugin-fcm

hi  i am using ionic1 push notification usif **FCM** functionality with the help of firebase i am trying to get notification with image but i am not able to do this correctly any one help how to do this

notification working fine but with image like flikart.